# Asp GridView firing Click event on the entire row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` which has `ID`, `Name` and `Type`.

Code behind:

```
protected void gridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.gridView, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
    }
}

public void gridView_Command(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
   // some code here //
}
```

The `GridView`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView" runat="server" OnRowCommand="gridView_Command" />
<columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" />
    <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" />
</columns>
```

The `Name` is click enabled because of the HyperlinkField. The problem here is I don't want the `gridview_Command` to be triggered if the row is clicked. I just want the `Name` field. For example, if the column of the `Type` is clicked, don't fire the `gridView_Command`.

Comment: Are you data-binding the grid on every postback?

Comment: Yes, I do it every postback

Comment: I edited my question. It shouldn't be the `gridView_RowDataBound`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Did you also mean to change `OnRowDataBound` to `OnRowCommand`?

Comment: Yes indeed . Sorry again ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that clear what you are trying to achieve, but if I understand correctly there are a few things you need to change.

1. You need to wrap your columns inside of the `<asp:Gridview>` tag.
2. You need to hook up your RowDataBound event.
3. You need to create a template column so you can use the CommandName parameter.
4. You need to filter for the CommandName parameter in your event to only respond to the click from the control you want.

`<asp:GridView ID="gridView" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gridView_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="gridView_Command" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
        <columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lb1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' CommandName="NameButton" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" />
        </columns>
    </asp:GridView>`

```
public void gridView_Command(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "NameButton")
    {
        var id = e.CommandArgument;

        // some code here //
    }
}
```

Using this example, you can respond to the event of a click on the "NameButton" only.

Comment: The first item in the things I needed to change is only a typo error. But this did the thing that I wanted. Thanks!